# Search for string with the most number of occurrence

Tags: php

```
$string = "apple grapes apple banana otherwords more words apple grapes apple orange orange orange orange orange orange orange";
```

Is there any PHP function that will return which string (banana, apple, grapes) has the most number of occurrence within a given string? In this example it should return `apple` though orange has the one with the most number.

Comment: @hanky-panky voted down and marked this as off topic after I didn't selected his answer. What is off topic with this, this is PHP programming?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See code + explanation.

```
<?php

$interesting = array('banana', 'apple', 'grapes');
$string = "apple grapes apple banana otherwords more words apple grapes apple orange";

// Explode into array
$array = explode(" ", $string);

// Group the values 
$count = array_count_values($array); 

// Sort the grouping by highest occurence to lowest
arsort($count);

// Get the keys of the most occurring
$keys = array_keys($count);

// compare key against the $interesting array for what you're interested in
$most_occurring = '';
foreach ($keys as $i) {
  if (in_array($i, $interesting, true)) {
      $most_occurring = $i;
      break;
  }
}

// Print output
echo "Most occurring $most_occurring, $count[$most_occurring] occurences.";

?>
```

Comment: In this solution 'other words' might occur most,remember I only need to check the 3 string (banana, apple, grapes)

Comment: Nice answer, but what is that last line? It prints `Most occurring apple[1], apple[0] occurences.`

Comment: A simple `echo $keys[0];` will do

Comment: Yeah, i made a minor mistake. Forgot $COUNT was the hash ref :)

Comment: This solution will return `orange`. I need to check only for the 3 string (banana, apple, grapes)

Comment: Check revised solution.
Define the interesting values you want, and then use in_array() against the $keys array to grab the one you want.

Answer (score 1):

Although the answer by **rurouni88** is very nice but it no longer caters for the added requirement, which is that not all words are important and you are specifying which words to look for. You can do

```
<?php

   $string = "apple grapes apple banana otherwords more words apple grapes apple orange orange orange orange orange orange orange";
   $words=array("banana", "apple", "grapes");

   foreach($words as $word)
   {
     $counts[$word]=substr_count($string,$word);
   }
   arsort($counts);
   reset($counts);
   if($counts[0]>0)
     echo key($counts);     // apple
   else
     echo "Your words are not present";
?>
```

**[Fiddle](http://codepad.org/F4jcAdV1)**

Comment: Thanks, i was getting along to that.
Interesting approach you've taken.
I like it, however I went with the in_array solution instead of substr_count. :)

Comment: That actually makes the code a little longer than what's necessary and it also grabs counts for those words which are not important and then discards them later. However you program neat and have good potential :)

Comment: The code will return `grapes` even if my given string is "xxxxxxxxx tttttttttttt other words";

Comment: Wow cant you add a simple if else? See the edit. You couldn't really have added one `if` condition and decided to unselect an answer based on that? Sorry but this isn't a spoon-feeding school.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
$string = "apple grapes apple banana otherwords more words apple grapes apple orange orange orange orange orange orange orange";
$array = explode(" ", $string);

$words = array_unique($array);
$counter = 0;
$returnWord = null;
foreach($words as $word){
   $currentWordCount = substr_count($string, $word);
   if($currentWordCount > $counter){
      $counter = $currentWordCount; 
      $returnWord = $word;
   }
}
echo "Most occurrences: ".$returnWord ." : ".$counter;

Most occurrences: orange : 7
```

EDIT:

```
$string = "apple grapes apple banana otherwords more words apple grapes apple orange orange orange orange orange orange orange";

$words = array("banana", "apple", "grapes");
$counter = 0;
$returnWord = null;
foreach($words as $word){
   $currentWordCount = substr_count($string, $word);
   if($currentWordCount > $counter){
      $counter = $currentWordCount; 
      $returnWord = $word;
   }
}
echo "Most occurrences: ".$returnWord ." : ".$counter;

Most occurrences: apple : 4
```

Comment: Please read my question.

Comment: Well...I've read it, and if you want to hardcode 3 strings that you want to count, you can just substitute `$words = array(your_words);`

Answer (score 0):

yes, it's called [substr_count](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr-count.php)!

it accepts the string, the name of the occurrence and the substring to analyze.

for example, if you want to check the max number of occurrences in that string, you could build an array with all the names you want to check and then for every value call this function.

example source code:

```
// initialize your string
$string = "apple grapes apple banana otherwords more words apple grapes apple orange";

// make an array with all the string names
$occurrences = explode(" ", $string);

// remove duplicate entries from the array
$occurrences = array_unique($occurrences);

// for every name, in an associative position, count the number of that occurrence in our string 
foreach ($occurrences as $occurrence) {
    $count[$occurrence] = substr_count($string, $occurrence);
}

// let see what it contains
var_dump($count);

// print out where it finds the max number of occorrences
echo "max occurrence found here: " . array_search(max($count), $count);
```

Answer (score 0):

The rurouni88's solution is good and elegant, but it has a little overhead due to sorting. For large data probably the best way is to write ad-hoc function in O(nm):

```
function max_occurrences($array, $valid) {
    $count = array();
    $maxValue = 0;
    $maxEl = "";
    foreach( $array as $v ){
        if ( ! in_array($v, $valid, true) )
            continue;
        isset ( $count[$v] ) ? $count[$v]++ : $count[$v]=1  ;
        if ( $count[$v] > $maxValue ) {
            $maxValue = $count[$v];
            $maxEl = $v;
        }
    }
    return $maxEl;
}

$string = "apple grapes apple banana otherwords more words apple grapes apple orange orange orange orange orange orange orange";
echo max_occurrences(explode(" ",$string), array("apple","grapes", "banana"));
```